# Creating a list composed of object property references

Tags: c#, list, object, reference

I am trying to do the following thing:
- From within a 1st method, I am going through a bunch of objects (of same type) and extracting pointers to specific properties into a list
- This list will then be fed to a another method elsewhere in my program at some point in time and has to modify all the properties (as per provided list) of the original objects

In other words, say we have the following class:

```
public class Something  
{  
    public SomeFlag = False;  
    public Something()  
    {  
    }  
}
```

Somewhere in the system, we have composed a related list of objects into List.
Now, we want to scan through this list and extract into "List< bool> flags" all the flags (by reference?):

```
List<bool> flags = new List<bool>();
foreach (var stuff in List<Something>)
{
  flags.Add(stuff.SomeFlag);
}
```

Finally, somewhere else, I want to update these flags, but the update should affect the original object:

```
public static void SetStates(List<bool> myList)
{
    // The flag should get set to true by reference in the original object
    myList.SomeFlag = True;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have messed around with 'ref', but went nowhere. Not sure there is any point mentioning it.
I just to extract some properties into a list that when modified affect the original object. So probably something to do with how to compile this list. Any idea?

Comment: You need a reference to the original object. What's stopping you just looping through List<Something> and setting them when you need to? So why can't you just pass in List<Something> into SetStates?

Comment: Doing this does not seem to affect the original object.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I thought List<Something> was basically a list made up of original objects? So by looping through them and modifying them you will be modifying the original object.

Comment: No, you are compiling a list of properties out of a list of objects - There are 2 lists in the story

Comment: Yes, List<Something> and List<bool> right? If so, then isn't List<Something> the list of original objects?

Comment: That is correct!

Comment: So if that's correct why can't you just pass the List<Something> into SetStates instead of List<bool> and loop over the Somethings and set the flag then?

Comment: Because my List<bool> will actually selectively pick amongst List<Something> (based on other criterias). I don't actually want the lot.

Answer (score 1):

Using `actions` could be one way to achive this:

```
public class Something
{
    public bool SomeFlag { get; set; }
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var somethings = new[] {new Something(), new Something()};

        var flags = new List<Action<bool>>();

        // create your list of 'pointers'
        foreach (var something in somethings)
        {
            flags.Add(x => something.SomeFlag = x);
        }

        // set them all to true
        foreach (var action in flags)
        {
            action(true);
        }

        // check the results
        foreach (var something in somethings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(something.SomeFlag);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C#, you cannot save a reference to a property value (like a pointer to the memory location where the value is stored). You only can save a reference to an object which contains this property value.

In your `var list = new List<Something>()`, you can store those references to the objects.

*Note that it's impossible for value types though. If `Something` is a `struct`, not a `class`, then the `list` will contain copies of the objects, not the references to the objects. So the rest of my answer assumes we're talking about `class Something`.*

You can define a property changing behavior and apply it using the list of the objects.

If you already know at compile time which properties and which values do you need, you can create a lambda and pass it around.

```
// Define the behavior and get the object list
Action<Something> setter = o => o.Someflag = true;
var objectList = new List<Something>();

// Call your processing method later on
SetProperties(objectList, setter);

void SetProperties<T>(List<T> objects, Action<T> setter)
{
    objects.ForEach(setter);
}
```

If you don't know at compile which properties and which values you will need, then things get much more complicated. You will need to use Reflection to obtain the property descriptors and to set the values.

Here is a simplified example:

```
// Define the behavior and get the object list
var objectList = new List<Something>();
string propertyName = "SomeFlag";
PropertyInfo pi = typeof(Something).GetProperty(propertyName);
MethodInfo setter = pi.GetSetMethod();
object value = true;

// Call your processing method later on
SetProperties(objectList, setter, value);

void SetProperties<T>(List<T> objects, MethodInfo setter, object value)
{
    var arguments = new object[] { value } ;
    objects.ForEach(o => setter.Invoke(o, arguments));
}
```